# IoT using Google Cloud Service IoT solutions (Weave): How to connect Raspberry Pi and lighting the LED?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to connect my raspberri pi with Google IoT Cloud solutions using Weave. I have done it already using AWS and IBM Bluemix, but could not find a way to do the same using Google Cloud. As per their documentation, it seems that some of the fies have been deprecated or not been updated. 
Moreover, they have been written in C language and I am not much of a C guy. I used Python for both the IBM Bluemix and AWS to connect my Pi to IoT and then establish the subscriber and exchange messages using MQTT gateway. 
Can anyone suggest anything regarding this?

[Google Weave getting started](https://developers.google.com/weave/guides/device-dev/getting-started)

To be more specific, certain packages which I saw in error logs while installing the below step:

```
make -C examples/host/light
```

it showed in logs the message like

```
could not find lldap
could not find llssh2
```

Even after installing them in my developer machine.

Due to error above, the below command

```
./out/host/examples/light/light
```

is not executed as the location

```
 /out/host/examples/light/light
```

is not created by the above `make` command. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try instead to use the new [Google Cloud IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core) product instead of Weave - full disclosure, I worked on it.  It's currently in [public beta](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/announcing-Cloud-IoT-Core-public-beta.html) and enables the scenarios you're trying to address. You should be able to use MQTT to communicate to/from your device.

There's a [high-level overview of the platform on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kcDL5BDe0s#t=0m0s) as well as an [industrial applications focused talk from Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFu5gpGEYj0).